# i18next: is there a maximum key length? or special characters not allowed in key?

Tags: i18next

I am trying to use the default language value itself as key in my usage of i18next to keep it simple.

Sometimes the messages are long and sometime have special chars like single quote/ double quote or apostrophe ...

Even though the resourceBundle is having this key value pair, i18next is still logging this as missing key.

Happens only for long text or keys with special chars mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

verified that only the key separator and ns separator only have to be replaced. Otherwise everything else look good.

Comment: what is the key and ns separator??